# How to insert an item between other two in an array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, object, swap

I have the following `object[] array`:

```
array[0] = obj_1;
array[1] = obj_2;
array[2] = obj_3;
array[3] = NULL;
array[4] = NULL;
```

And I need to insert another element between the `array[1]` and `array[2]` like this:

```
array[0] = obj_1;
array[1] = obj_2;
array[2] = obj_New;
array[3] = obj_3;
array[4] = NULL;
```

I can't use `List` before someone suggest. Any ideas of how can I do that?

Comment: Arrays are fixed length structures that do not support the dynamic insertion of new entries. If you want to insert between two elements it would be better to choose `List`.

Comment: @S.Akbari Well, you don't _have_ to use `List` but it's a _lot_ easier.  Lists uses an array internally so it is _possible_.

Comment: @S.Akbari, I know tha `Lists` have those dynamic insertions, but I really **need** to use an array

Comment: Why can't you use `List`?  Is this a puzzle or a real restriction?

Comment: @DStanley, it's the **challenge** not to use `List`.

Comment: Does the challenge allow you to ask strangers on the internet for the answer?  Seems like the point of the challenge would be for you to _think_.

Comment: @DStanley, it's not cheating because I really don't know how to do it. I don't have full mastery of the language and I'm supposed to find the answer no matter where.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct way. You need to move the elements first, and then set the value at desired index.

Below is sample snippet (without any array index checks)

```
void InsertItem(object[] array, int index, object val)
{
  for(int i=index;i<array.Length;i++)
  {
     array[i] = array[i-1];
  }
  array[index] = val;

}
```

Do note that Array once created are allocated contigigous location, and are of fixed size. They cannot be arbitrary moved.

If you require various such operations, i would suggest [linked list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx) data structure.

Comment: The movement is literally in the answer.  This answer, given your restrictions towards array-only functionality, is accurate.

Comment: This code overwrites all values at indexes greater than `index` with the value found at `index - 1`. E.g., calling `InsertItem(array, 1, 9)` on `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }` returns `{ 1, 9, 1, 1, 1 }`.

Answer (score 0):

From your post, it sounds like you want to pop the last item off the array and not the first one.

If so, like Tilak has suggested, the simplest way is to take/determine the index where the item has to be inserted and move the items from current position to the next subsequent position and finally add the new item in the given index. You would want to watch out for what happens if the array is already full, do you want to drop the last item or not?

We can optimize a bit in Tilak's code, by not overwriting the array[index] item twice, once in loop and once outside.

I will do it a bit different, I will start from end and go up, so you can avoid a temp variable.

```
    void InsertItem(object[] array, int index, object val)
    {
      for(int i=array.Length - 1; i > index; i--)
      {
         array[i] = array[i-1];
      }

      array[index] = val;
    }
```

Like others have already said, List or LinkedList will be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed a light to do it. I used Tilak's example as my base and I did the following code (With some more things like add in the end of the list and with a starting empty array):

```
object[] array = new object[0];
public void Insert(int index, object val)
    {
       Array.Resize(ref array, array.Length + 1);

        if (index >= array.Length-1)
        {
            array[array.Length - 1] = val;
            return;
        }

       for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
       {
           if (index == i)
           {
               for (int idx = array.Length; idx > index; idx--)
               {
                   array[idx-1] = array[idx-2];
               }
               array[i] = val;
               return;
            }
        }
   }
```

It is completely functional and the `Array.Resize` activates every time that I insert something so that my array will always be with the exactly number of slots that I need.